# Basic reltionship gives the error Property [post] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

In my application, I have users and posts. and user have followers. the followers table is defined as:

```
user_id
follower_id
```

and than if User Model I have this relationships to get follows and followers:

```
function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
}

function follows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
}
```

In user controller I'm trying to access the follows with:

```
$follows = $authed->follows;
```

Which works pretty fine, but than I try to access the posts made by that user.
There is a relationship in User model for that to which is defined as:

```
function posts(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Posts', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

But when I try to access posts with:

```
$follows = $authed->follows;
$followingPosts = $follows->posts->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

*It gives me the error:* **Property [posts] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Answer (score 1):

`$follows = $authed->follows;` is a `Collection` of `User` objects, not a single object, thats why you are getting that error

Comment: but when I try to get $follows->posts as post in foreach it's still not working.